# multiple users on one wms layer - style and filter

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, wms

I am using geoserver to show Points data from MySql in OL.
The data saved in one table for all the users - 'Points' with a geometry field and Id of the user.
I want to be able to let the users to see only their data, and also to style this features, but i didnt find any solution to filter or styling this data **not** from the geoserver panel.
I need to filter the data by the Id number of the user, and then he see only his data, it is possible to do it like this? from the js file?
if not, there is a other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply an [OGC Filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html) or a [CQL Filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) to your getmap request to restrict what a specified user sees in the map. Note that this isn't secure as any one who uses another client will see all the points (or any subset they want).

For a custom styling solution you can follow the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187187/how-to-add-sld-style-to-a-wms-layer-dynamically-through-javascript).